# std::is_constructible on type with non-public destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, type-traits

What is the expected result for [`std::is_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) on a type with a private or protected destructor?

For instance, I can still construct such an object on the heap even though only a friend can free it:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Foo
{
    friend void freeFoo(Foo*);
public:
    Foo()
    {}
private:
    // Destructor is private!
    ~Foo()
    {}
};

void freeFoo(Foo* f)
{
    delete f;  // deleting a foo is fine here because of friendship
}

int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Foo();
    // delete f;   // won't compile: ~Foo is private
    freeFoo(f);    // fine because of friendship


    if(!std::is_constructible<Foo>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "is_constructible failed" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The final check for `is_constructible` will fail on both gcc and Visual C++ ([gcc demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09e361eabcdf1553)).

Is that the required behavior by the standard? If so, is there any way to check whether the type has a specific constructor, regardless of the access specifier on the destructor?

Comment: Related: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/bPwd3UkZa6w

Comment: @Caramiriel Unfortunately it is not directly addressing the problem. `is_destructible` explicitly depends on the accessibility of the destructor, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The C++14 FD defines `is_constructible` as follows:

> Given the following function declaration:
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> add_rvalue_reference_t<T> create() noexcept;
> ```
>
> the predicate condition for a template specialization
>   `is_constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the
>   following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented
>   variable `t`:
>
> ```
> T t(create<Args>()...);
> ```
>
> **Access checking is performed as if in a context unrelated to `T`
>   and any of the `Args`. Only the validity of the immediate context of
>   the variable initialization is considered.** [ *Note*: The evaluation
>   of the initialization can result in side effects such as the
>   instantiation of class template specializations and function template
>   specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined functions, and
>   so on. Such side effects are not in the “immediate context” and can
>   result in the program being ill-formed. *—end note* ]

Now the question essentially reduces to "Is the destructor call in the immediate context of the variable initialization?" [class.dtor]/11:

> A destructor is invoked implicitly
>
> - for a constructed object with static storage duration (3.7.1) at program termination (3.6.3),
> - for a constructed object with automatic storage duration (3.7.3) when the block in which an object is created exits (6.7),
> - for a constructed temporary object when its lifetime ends (12.2).
>
> **In each case, the context of the invocation is the context of the
>   construction of the object.**

Thus the destructor invocation is in the context of the construction (which is presumably synonymous to initialization here), which implies that it is considered and causes the trait to return `false`.
I believe this to be underspecified (e.g. immediate vs not-explicitly-immediate context?), but intuitively I expect a conforming implementation to mark the expression `NotDestructible()` as ill-formed - either SFINAE-friendly or not (preferably the former). Never well-formed, though.
[Clang with libc++, libstdc++ and GCC do say that it's invalid, SFINAE-friendly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d4c16ec2739d5dc).

---

> If so, is there any way to check whether the type has a specific
>   constructor, regardless of the access specifier on the destructor?

What about using `new`?

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
class is_only_constructible
{
    template <typename, typename=void> struct test : std::false_type {};
    template <typename U>
    struct test<U, decltype(void(new U(std::declval<Args>()...)))> : std::true_type {};

public:
    static constexpr bool value = test<T>::value;
};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5c68c8b14fc653e). Consistent traits can be easily established: Take the `is_only_constructible` trait and combine it with `is_destructible` (clearly the latter returns `false` when combined with private destructors).

Comment: I'm wondering: if the intention of the Committee was to have `is_constructible<T, Args...>::value` yield `true` even when `T`'s destructor is inaccessible (which seems to be what you claim), why not specifying that trait's behavior in terms of a `new` expression?

Comment: @AndyProwl This is not what I mean. I think the comittee didn't properly consider this case and thus the text is underspecified.

Comment: I see. I probably misunderstood this statement then: "As far as I can see, a destructor call is not in the immediate context of the initialization and should thus not be considered".

Comment: All right, so what you're claiming (correct me if I'm wrong) is that the current wording implies that `is_constructible` should yield `true`, but that this was not the intention of the Committee. Did I get it right?

Comment: @AndyProwl Okay, I'm sorry, seriously. Didn't have my coffee yet. I meant to say that I think GCC and VC++ are right, and the trait should yield false, because the destructor call is in the context considered. Updated my answer.

Comment: @AndyProwl I'm not sure about the intention. An EWG-issue would perhaps be appropriate, don't you think?

Comment: What about pathological `new` overloads, could they cause problems?

Comment: @Yakk Okay, what about placement `new`? Can that be overloaded?

Comment: @Columbo: Maybe, although I'm so used to the Standard being super-obscure that I sort of stopped reasoning about what the actual wording does imply, and rather started considering what the Committee's intention was more likely to be when writing it. The end result is the same ("I don't know and I might be wrong"), but at least I save some nerve lifetime by not bouncing from one ambiguous paragraph to another :)

Comment: The "is_only_constructible" solution doesn't seem to be working correctly with MSVC2017 15.7.5, on the IDE hovering the mouse it seems to work, but when compiling and running it always returns false.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting paragraph [meta.unary.prop]/7 of the C++ Standard (Draft N4296):

> Given the following function declaration:
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> add_rvalue_reference_t<T> create() noexcept;
> ```
>
> the predicate condition for a template specialization `is_constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented variable `t`:
>
> ```
> T t(create<Args>()...);
> ```

In other words, `is_constructible<T, Args...>::value` yields `false` if the destructor is not accessible.

Comment: So what about the second part of the question: Is there any way to check whether the type has a specific constructor, regardless of the access specifier on the destructor?

Comment: @ComicSansMS: I'm afraid I can't answer that part (at least, not from the top of my head), although I suspect the answer is "no".

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Checking for existence of an ordinary member function is not that hard, but constructors are tricky. I guess this could be considered an oversight in `type_traits`.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I have a possible workaround in my answer.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: I don't know why, but for some reason I kept thinking about the detection of a private/protected constructor, while the problem is clearly the access specifier of the destructor. Columbo's solution is indeed what I should have thought of.