# If a destructor is deleted, will the compiler still implicitly generate a default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

If a destructor is deleted, will the compiler still implicitly generate a default constructor?

The following code can be compiled by GCC:

```cpp
struct A
{
    ~A() = delete;
    int x;
    int y;
    virtual void foo()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *pmc = new A; // Allowed by the compiler GCC, but causes memory leak
    return 0;
}
```

This suggests that GCC believes it can implicitly generate a default constructor in this situation. The assembly code for the default constructor can also be viewed on Godbolt:

```
A::A() [base object constructor]:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:vtable for A+16
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], rdx
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

However, when checking with type traits, the answer is negative:

```cpp
cout << is_default_constructible<A>::value; // false
```

So, does `is_default_constructible` represent the attitude of the C++ standard? That is to say, at the language standard level, the generation of a default constructor is not allowed, but at the compiler implementation level, the generation of a default constructor is allowed.

Is this correct?

Comment: Side note unlearn to use `new`. Your code as it is has a memory leak already. If possible avoid dynamic allocation altogether (In your code just use `A pmc`) or  use `std::make_unique<A>()`.

Comment: I really love the [table](https://www.foonathan.net/2019/02/special-member-functions/) by [@HowardHinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant) and have always referred to it. Note that for the purpose of this question, explicitly deleted counts as user-defined.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Except that `A pmc;` doesn't compile because of a deleted destructor.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Huh... I missed that... probably because I never thought or can't think of a use case with a deleted destructor unless maybe for optimization(never tried it anyway). I always assumed that compilers will not call destructors for trivial classes anyway

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28085847 (To check if a type is default constructible even if it's not destructible, you can use `requires { ::new ((void*) nullptr) T(); }` / `requires { std::construct_at((T*) nullptr); }`)

Comment: @PepijnKramer • perhaps for an intentionally leaking non-destructible singleton.  Hard to think of legitimate use cases.

Answer (score 5):

Yes (to the question in the title), a default constructor is always implicitly declared if no other constructor is user-declared, although it may be defined as deleted if subobjects can't be default-initialized or destructed. Nothing about the destructor of the class itself is relevant:

> If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted ([[dcl.fct.def]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def)).

- [[class.default.ctor] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#1)

`std::is_default_constructible<A>` fails because the `std::is_(*_)constructible` traits do not *only* check whether the object can be constructed. They instead check whether a definition of a variable with the corresponding types in direct-initialization would be well-formed, i.e. here whether

```
A a();
```

would be well-formed, except that the declaration is not interpreted as a function declaration. Such a variable definition is only well-formed if the destructor is also usable.

---

> That is to say, at the language standard level, the generation of a default constructor is not allowed, but at the compiler implementation level, the generation of a default constructor is allowed. Is this correct?

No, this question doesn't make any sense to begin with. If the standard specifies that a constructor is not implicitly declared/defined, then a compiler conforming to the standard can't possibly do it another way.

Comment: I don't think "Yes" is the correct response to "at the language standard level, the generation of a default constructor is not allowed, but at the compiler implementation level, the generation of a default constructor is allowed".

Comment: @WeijunZhou I was answering the title question. Clarified now.

Comment: It's worth noting that the implicitly defaulted default constructor is defined as deleted if the destructor is deleted (https://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#2.6).

Comment: @JanSchultke, if it is deleted for a subobject.

Comment: Is an object considered its own subobject though?

Comment: @JanSchultke No, it is not. See the first sentences of https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.object-2. The rule wouldn't make sense otherwise either. The destructor of the class is not needed to construct a complete object, but generally the destructor of subobjects are needed in case of exceptions from the complete object's default constructor. That's also why I chose "_declared_" in my answer. In the example of OP the default constructor will not be deleted.

Comment: Rather than worrying about `A a()` not being interpreted as a function declaration, I'd suggest simply saying that `is_(*)_constructible` traits simply tests if `A a{}` would be well formed.

Comment: @Peter But that's not what it tests. `struct A { A(std::initializer_list<int>); };` will fail `std::is_default_constructible`, but `A a{};` will be well-formed. `std::default_initializable` would test both.